# uint64_t or int64_t not found when compiling gcc 12.2.0

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I'm a beginner with Linux and I'm updating GCC but I have an error on compiling.

The command I use :

```
../configure --prefix=/usr --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go,objc,obj-c++
```

When I run `make` it gives the following error :

```
Configuring stage 1 in ./gcc
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... ok
checking GCC_EXEC_PREFIX variable... ok
checking whether to place generated files in the source directory... no
checking whether a default linker was specified... no
checking whether a default dsymutil was specified... no
checking whether a default assembler was specified... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 accepts -g... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gnatbind... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gdc... no
checking whether the D compiler works... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for inline... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... unknown
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... unknown
checking size of ino_t... 0
checking size of dev_t... 0
checking size of void *... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking for long long... no
checking for int8_t... no
checking for int16_t... no
checking for int32_t... no
checking for int64_t... no
checking for unsigned long long int... no
checking for long long int... no
checking for intmax_t... no
checking for intptr_t... no
checking for uint8_t... no
checking for uint16_t... no
checking for uint32_t... no
checking for uint64_t... no
checking for uintmax_t... no
checking for uintptr_t... no
configure: error: uint64_t or int64_t not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4663: configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gcc-12.2.0/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:27037: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gcc-12.2.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1072: all] Error 2
```

**If anyone has an idea about this, I'll take it.**

TY ALL

Comment: I would just install a prebuilt version of gcc. Unless you have very special requirements that seems the simple thing to do.

Comment: Your system seems to lack many standard header files. It seems very odd. Have you installed the base development packages needed? Like for example `build-essential` on Debian-based systems (like Ubuntu)?

Comment: Looks like `configure` script cannot locate any existing toolchains on your system.

Comment: I find this part interesting *"checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no"* Seems like you might have a C compiler installed, but no C++ compiler. To build the newest compiler version, you need to have an older compiler already installed. You cannot start from zero.

Comment: You're making the rookie mistake of only caring about the *last* error messages (about things not found), since the *first* errors are what matter.  All those checks are to find things (compilers, libraries, headers) that are *already* on your system, since gcc source is built by bootstrapping. Although your system has a C compiler (gcc) installed, it does not have standard or other headers needed to build source code of gcc itself - and missing `uint64_t`, etc, are consequences of that.  You need to install a working compiler (with headers and possibly libraries) before trying to build gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Check through the config.log files generated during the attempted build (probably /gcc/config.log).  One of them will tell you exactly what went wrong, which isn't necessarily that uint64_t was not found.  For example, GCC 11 and later require the bootstrap compiler to support C++ 11, and the test for uint64_t is one of the first that adds -std=c++11 to the bootstrap compiler's command line.  If the native compiler on your build system is a GCC older than 4.8.3 you'll get that uint64_t error.

Comment: Good observation that might help someone in the future.  In this case, though, output like `checking for stdlib.h... no`, `checking for string.h... no`, and `checking size of int... 0` indicate something more serious, I'd think.  `sizeof( int )` is zero?!?!  I'd hope even GCC 1.0 could get *that* right.